# How to unit test a method which will invoke a delegate in a timer handler?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to verify the correctness of delegate invoking, but i must wait the timer raise it's event(about 5 seconds), so i should do some operation like Thread.Sleep(5000) in my unit test code, and i think it is not a best practise in unit test.

Is there another better idea for this situation?

Comment: Tests should be (F)ast, (I)solated, (R)epeatable, (S)elf validating, (T)imely so never insert a Thread.Sleep in a test

Answer (score 2):

Mock the timer and raise the event without waiting

Comment: Mock the timer is a good idea sometimes, but the problem is the timer is not directly created by the method tested, it is only used in subfunction which is invoked by the method tested, and the delegate is also invoked by this subfunction, so i don't know how to test it.

Comment: Then, if I understood correctly, I would try to decouple the timer. Anyway could you show us some code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to decouple the code which uses timer and make it depend on some abstraction. Lets say your own interface `ITimer` and inject it as the dependency.

Then it becomes very easy to mock out `ITimer` to raise the event immediately.